# Is there any way to ask user questions in Jenkins job parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to ask user some questions before he/she builds. Questions will be like

**Are you sure you have included all the files?** (Answers: Yes, No )

**Have you created a ticket in JIRA related to this fix?** (Answer: Yes, No )

Is there any way I can do it? is there any plugin available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A freestyle job can be configured to build with parameters. See:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

You can configure the parameter type (string, boolean, drop down etc), give a description of the parameter and a default value. The job parameters can even include more complex things like validation rules:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin

Or groovy scripts:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in

Or values shown in one parameter list change depending on the value of another:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin

Your user then has to start the job by building with parameters - in effect being shown the parameter and descriptions (a bit like being asked the question).

Further validation can be done before initiating build steps using the 'Prepare an environment for the run' from the:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Build steps can be made optional based on user responses using:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin
or
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

I've used all of the above to refine the choices the user has and what gets done with/because of those choices. I'm using Jenkins 2.116 in process of planning for upgrade to pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **input** in your pipeline builds, with the questions you interested to provide to user. You can read more of usage in official doc of Jenkins here - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/

Comment: There is no way we can do it in Freestyle Project jobs?

Comment: not that I know about and if you do not have limittation in usage of frestyle vs pipelins, I would strongly suggest to move to pipelines, cause you will get much more flexibility