# Manual approval step between two freestyle Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have created two freestyle Jenkins job1 and Job2. Job1 is the upstream job for Job2.

I try to add manual approval after completion job1 successfully to approve job2 build. But I didn't find any plugin/options in freestyle.

I am able to add the same in Jenkins pipeline job by using input plugin.

Please help me on the same

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to ask user questions in Jenkins job parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560778/is-there-any-way-to-ask-user-questions-in-jenkins-job-parameter)

Comment: No. My question is about approval task between two freestyle Jenkins jobs